# ACL/Firewall/ADなど：アクセス権のルータによる設定とサーバによる設定の違いについて

Tags: network

漠然としたご質問で申し訳ございません。
アクセス権を制御したい場合、ACL/Firewall/ADなどが利用できると理解しております。

- ACLについては、ルータ側（ハードウェア）での設定とサーバＯＳ側（ソフトウェア）での設定が可能
- Firewallについても、ハードウェア方式とソフトウェア方式（WAF）が存在する
- ADについては、サーバＯＳ側（ソフトウェア）で設定可能

と通信の色々なタイミングで色々な方法が混在している気がしており、どのような思想で全体設計するものかが分かりかねております。

ハードウェア方式での設定の場合
×稼働後の変更が難しい（ハードウェアの保守担当者に設定変更依頼が発生）
〇ルータの転送時点での制御になるため、ソフトウェアでどのような設定をしても優先適用される？

ソフトウェア方式での設定の場合
〇稼働後の変更が容易

との認識ですが、
Q1.ベストプラクティスとして、どのような設計思想で設定するのが好ましいか
Q2.ソフトウェア方式で設定した場合、アプリケーション領域で独自に制御するものなのか、
　パケットヘッダを書き換えて、ルータでの設定と同様により低次元レイヤで制御されるものなのか
ご教示いただけませんでしょうか。

そもそも前提の理解が誤っている場合、ご指摘いただけると幸いです。

Comment: 何に対するアクセス権なのかが質問を読むだけでは読み取れなかったので、追記してもらうと回答が付きやすいかもしれません。

Comment: @cubick 様
早速ご教示いただき有難うございます。
漠然とフォルダ（ファイル）に対するアクセス権でイメージしておりました。
例えば、A事業部とB事業部のフォルダについてA事業部はA事業部のメンバーのみ、B事業部はB事業部のメンバーのみと構成したい場合に、
ルータやFirewall（IPアドレス単位）で制御するのか、ADのドメインで制御するのか、を決定する際に何が決め手になるのかが知りたいという意図になります。
もし勉強不足の箇所があればご教示ください。